# Compare and Insert data into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one is temp table and other one is database table.I need to compare two tables based on MM and ProjectID.If data is present in @mtts but not in tbl_snapshot then i have to insert it in tbl_sanpshot

> @mtts
>   table([MM],[YYYY],[month_Start],[month_Finish],[ProjectID],[ProjectedBillable],[ProjectedPayable],[ActualBilled],[ActualPaid],[Total_To_Bill],[Total_To_Pay])
>
> tbl_Snapshot
>   ([MM],[YYYY],[month_Start],[month_Finish],[ProjectID],[ProjectedBillable],[ProjectedPayable],[ActualBilled],[ActualPaid],[Total_To_Bill],[Total_To_Pay]).

Iam new to sql.so please help me on this

Comment: Another option is the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` and `EXISTS` to solve your problem, try this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Snapshot([MM],[YYYY],[month_Start],[month_Finish],
                         [ProjectID],[ProjectedBillable],[ProjectedPayable],
                         [ActualBilled],[ActualPaid],[Total_To_Bill],
                         [Total_To_Pay])
SELECT *
FROM mtts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_Snapshot)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more options apart from what John Woo suggested.

**Using Left Join**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Snapshot
SELECT *
FROM @mtts mtts 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Snapshot ss ON mtts.MM = ss.MM AND mtts.ProjectID = ss.ProjectID
WHERE ss.MM IS NULL AND ss.tbl_Snapshot IS NULL
```

**Using Merge Statement (Will work from Sql Server 2008 onwards)**

```
MERGE tbl_Snapshot AS ss
USING (SELECT * FROM @mtts) AS mtts
ON mtts.MM = ss.MM AND mtts.ProjectID = ss.ProjectID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT([MM],[YYYY],[month_Start],[month_Finish],[ProjectID],[ProjectedBillable],[ProjectedPayable],
       [ActualBilled],[ActualPaid],[Total_To_Bill],[Total_To_Pay])
VALUES(mm.[MM],mm.[YYYY],mm.[month_Start],mm.[month_Finish],mm.[ProjectID],mm.[ProjectedBillable],mm.[ProjectedPayable],
       mm.[ActualBilled],mm.[ActualPaid],mm.[Total_To_Bill],mm.[Total_To_Pay]);
```

**It is a very dirty way (CAST to VARCHAR, then MERGE and finally COMPARE)**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Snapshot
SELECT *
FROM @mtts mtts  
WHERE CAST(mtts.MM AS vARCHAR(10)) + CAST(mtts.ProjectID AS VARCHAR(10))
NOT IN (SELECT CAST(ss.MM AS vARCHAR(10)) + CAST(ss.ProjectID AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM tbl_Snapshot ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

Insert into tbl_Snapshot
select * from @mtts
where [MM] not  in(select [MM] from tbl_Snapshot)
and [ProjectID] not in (select [ProjectID] from tbl_Snapshot)

Thanks,

Venkat